# Server responding with response code 400 when making http head request using httpurlconnection

Tags: java, http, postman, okhttp, httpurlconnection

To a certain website , i am making HTTP head request to get header data using java. I have used the following code to do that.

```
String url2 = "https://pagalworld.com.se/siteuploads/files/sfd14/6934/Har Har Shambhu Ringtone_320(PagalWorld.com.se).mp3";
    String req_method = "HEAD";
    HttpsURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
        URL UrlConnection = new URL(url2);
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) UrlConnection.openConnection();
        String host = UrlConnection.getHost().toString()+":80";
        conn.setRequestMethod(req_method);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Host", host);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection","keep-alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty(DownloadApiConfig.USER_AGENT_REQUEST_HEADER, DownloadApiConfig.USER_AGENT_REQUEST_HEADER_VALUE);
        System.out.println("Host:Port = "+host);
        Map<String,List<String>> data = conn.getRequestProperties();
        System.out.println("Connection code : "+conn.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println("Connection Msg : "+conn.getResponseMessage());
        for(String key:data.keySet()){
            System.out.println(key + " " + data.get(key));
        }
        
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        conn.disconnect();
    }
```

Now the problem is , Server is responding with response code 400 (Bad request). But when i am making the same request from postman with same request headers, it gives response code 200 (Ok).
[http head request using Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpPC2.png)

Another thing is, if i am making the request with same request headers as before using okhttp client library then also it's responding with response code 200.

Now what's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't found any major issue on your code. I've tried to run your code inside one of my Android project. To avoid `NetworkOnMainThreadException` I've run the code snippet inside a thread. Then run it and found the expected response header in the log.

### Possible Solutions (What can you do now?)

1. Try run my `callApi()` method inside your project.
2. Change your url to `https://pagalworld.com.se/siteuploads/files/sfd14/6934/Har%20Har%20Shambhu%20Ringtone_320(PagalWorld.com.se).mp3` (replaced SPACE with `%20`). There is a chance for BAD request with white space URL.

### Here is the significant output

```
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: null HTTP/1.1 200 OK
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: Accept-Ranges bytes
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: Age 693
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: CF-Cache-Status HIT
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: CF-RAY 73f0ccbd1a5169b1-DAC
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: Connection keep-alive
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: content-disposition attachment
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: Content-Length 1221768
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: Content-Type application/octet-stream
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: Date Tue, 23 Aug 2022 03:35:42 GMT
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: Expect-CT max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: last-modified Thu, 11 Aug 2022 14:41:49 GMT
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: NEL {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: Report-To {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=nywwKM746VO8KiwrIJAIq6hoJ1D8eJphddRHtpP%2BkXxWPQCJayYi23um4V7mlUXd4kdWOXN%2FrXrTN6NA7sZWa%2BzU4L6tCx2v28VAkH51TPNfDVbeHGTHgwY8PCuulIdN3ek%2FloEn"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: Server cloudflare
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: Vary Accept-Encoding
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: X-Android-Received-Millis 1661225741490
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: X-Android-Response-Source NETWORK 200
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: X-Android-Selected-Protocol http/1.1
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: X-Android-Sent-Millis 1661225741442
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: x-content-type-options nosniff
I/System.out: ConnHeadRes: x-nginx-upstream-cache-status MISS
```

#### What I've changed in the code?

1. Run the code inside a thread
2. Update `USER_AGENT_REQUEST_HEADER` field and value.
3. Get response headers in a `Map` object.
4. Iterate the Map object and print key-value in log.

### Here is the code sample:

```
void callApi() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            String url2 = "https://pagalworld.com.se/siteuploads/files/sfd14/6934/Har Har Shambhu Ringtone_320(PagalWorld.com.se).mp3";
            String req_method = "HEAD";
            HttpsURLConnection conn = null;
            try {
                System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
                URL UrlConnection = new URL(url2);
                conn = (HttpsURLConnection) UrlConnection.openConnection();
                String host = UrlConnection.getHost() + ":80";
                conn.setRequestMethod(req_method);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Host", host);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("user-agent", "android");
                System.out.println("Host:Port = " + host);
                Map<String, List<String>> data = conn.getRequestProperties();
                System.out.println("Connection code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
                System.out.println("Connection Msg : " + conn.getResponseMessage());

                for (String key : data.keySet()) {
                    System.out.println(key + " " + data.get(key));
                }

                Map<String, List<String>> responseHeader = conn.getHeaderFields();
                for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : responseHeader.entrySet()) {
                    for (String value: entry.getValue()) {
                        System.out.println("ConnHeadRes: " + entry.getKey() + " " + value);
                    }
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

So, as far I understand I can say, there is no issue in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your ans.The second point of your answer has  solved the problem.